# Getting the value of sentences

Tags: list-manipulation, string-manipulation

I have a list, `importance`, that assigns a "value" to each word in some text, like such:

```
{ {the, 0.9}, {and, 1}, {red, 2.1} }
```

And I also have a list of sentences, with no periods. What I am trying to do is get the 'value' of each of sentences, by taking each word, finding it's 'value' in `importance`, and then finds the sum of the values of all the words in that sentence.

Here is an example input/output:

```
{"the and", "red the", "and and"}

{ {"the and", 1.9}, {"red the", 3}, {"and and", 2} }
```

I have tried all sorts of things with Table and Map, but nothing has even come close. Is there an elegant way to do this?

Answer (score 5):

Function, takes a string sentence and importance list:

```
fn = {#1,Tr[Replace[StringSplit[#1], Append[Rule @@@ #2, _ -> 0], 1]]} &;
```

Set up some dummy data, map function over list of inputs:

```
imp={{"the", 0.9}, {"and", 1}, {"red", 2.1}};
input = {"the and thou", "red the book", "and and ahh one, two, three"};
fn[#, imp] & /@ input
```

> {{"the and thou", 1.9}, {"red the book", 3.}, {"and and ahh one, two, three", 2}}

Comment: (+1) a typo in the last line: `imp` should be `importance`. Also, since `importance` is defined as a list of rules, you don't need `Rule@@@` in the first line.

Comment: @kglr - thanks for catch, actually an anti-typo: I'd lazily cut-n-pasted the definition in answer, but used the one in OP format (not a rules list). Fixed.

Answer (score 4):

One possible way

```
importance = {"the" -> 0.9, "and" -> 1, "red" -> 2.1};
input = {"the and me", "red the pluto", "and and mikey mouse"};
doIt[str_String] := Module[{m},
  m = StringSplit[str];
  m = Plus @@ (m /. importance);
  m = Cases[m, x_ /; NumericQ[x]];
  {str, m}
  ];

doIt[#] & /@ input
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: If there are words in input that aren't in importance, it will just add them, so the result will be something like 1.8+by+something. Is there a way to make all those other words just 0? So the result would, in that example, just be 1.8?

Comment: Yes, there is away, but you need to make sure the specification of the problem is complete. This was not mentioned in your post :)

Comment: Oh sorry! I didn't mean to say that it wasn't right - this answer is brilliant, thank you. I was just wondering. This only came up after I tested your code and realized some of the words were missing. I'm sure I know how to do it, but I'm sure it's not the most elegant way, either.

Comment: Please try now. I did it quickly but you can test it :)

Answer (score 2):

**1.**

All words have values (like in the question)

```
v = {{"the", 0.9}, {"and", 1.}, {"red", 2.1}};

w = {"the and", "red the", "and and"};

s = StringSplit @ w;

Transpose[{w, Total /@ s /. Rule @@@ v}]
```

{{"the and", 1.9}, {"red the", 3.}, {"and and", 2.}}

**2.**

Only some words have values (like in Nasser's answer)

```
v = {{"the", 0.9}, {"and", 1.}, {"red", 2.1}};

w = {"the and me", "red the pluto", "and and mickey mouse"};

s = StringSplit @ w;
```

Create association for replacement

```
a = <|AssociationMap[0 &] /@ s, Rule @@@ v|>
```

<|"the" -> 0.9, "and" -> 1., "me" -> 0, "red" -> 2.1, "pluto" -> 0,
"mickey" -> 0, "mouse" -> 0|>

Using `MapApply` (new in 13.1)

```
Transpose[{w, MapApply[Plus, s /. a]}]
```

{{"the and me", 1.9}, {"red the pluto", 3.}, {"and and mickey mouse",
2.}}

Answer (score 1):

```
weightedStrings[strings_, weights_, func_ : Total, default_ : 0] := 
 Map[s |-> {s, func @ Lookup[Rule@@@weights, StringSplit[s], default]}]@strings
```

***Examples:***

```
v = {{"the", 0.9}, {"and", 1.}, {"red", 2.1}};

input1 = {"the and", "red the", "and and"};

weightedStrings[input1, v]
```

> ```
> {{"the and", 1.9}, {"red the", 3.}, {"and and", 2.}}
> ```

```
weightedStrings[input1, v, Apply[Times], 1]
```

> ```
> {{"the and", 0.9}, {"red the", 1.89}, {"and and", 1.}}
> ```

```
weightedStrings[input1, v, FOO]
```

> ```
> {{"the and", FOO[{0.9, 1.}]},   
>  {"red the", FOO[{2.1, 0.9}]},   
>  {"and and", FOO[{1., 1.}]}}
> ```

Using @ciao's input example:

```
input2 = {"the and thou", "red the book", "and and ahh one, two, three"};

weightedStrings[input2, v]
```

> ```
>  {{"the and thou", 1.9},   
>   {"red the book", 3.},   
>   {"and and ahh one, two, three", 2.}}
> ```

```
weightedStrings[input2, v, Apply[Times], 1]
```

> ```
>  {{"the and thou", 0.9},   
>   {"red the book", 1.89},   
>   {"and and ahh one, two, three", 1.}}
> ```

```
weightedStrings[input2, v, FOO, "blah"]
```

> ```
> {{"the and thou", FOO[{0.9, 1., "blah"}]},   
>  {"red the book", FOO[{2.1, 0.9, "blah"}]},   
>  {"and and ahh one, two, three",   
>   FOO[{1., 1., "blah", "blah", "blah", "blah"}]}}
> ```

Answer (score 1):

**Using `Lookup`:**

```
w = {{"the", 0.9}, {"and", 1}, {"red", 2.1}};
lut = Rule @@@ w;
strWeight[str_String, lut_List : lut] := Module[
  {s = StringSplit[str] // Map[StringTrim], t1},
  t1 = Lookup[lut, #, 0] & /@ s;
  Echo[Transpose[{s, t1}]];
  Total[t1]
  ]
```

---

*Usage:*

1. The look up table uses its default value and it can be supplied as the second argument.
2. The `Echo` command can be commented out, if not required.

---

```
strWeight /@ {"the and thou", "red the book", 
  "and and ahh one, two, three"}
strWeight /@ {"the sound of the red car and the blue one"}
```

---

*Result:*

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Using `StringCases`:

```
v = {{"the", 0.9}, {"and", 1.}, {"red", 2.1}};

w = {"the and", "red the", "and and"};

s = Total@StringCases[#, Except[WhitespaceCharacter] ..] & /@ w;

Thread[{#, s /. Rule @@@ v}] &@w

{{"the and", 1.9}, {"red the", 3.}, {"and and", 2.}}
```